# Perl: if a subroutine from a package prints something to my terminal, how do I use its output in my program without changing the package?

Tags: perl

I am using a package in Perl (Biomart) that prints out the results of a query. The syntax that prints the output looks like this:

```
$query_runner->execute($query);
$query_runner->printResults();
```

And that prints the results of my query to my terminal. Instead, I would like the stuff that's printed to be printed to an output file. I tried:

```
$output = "@ARGV[1]";
open OUT , ">$output" or die "Can't open $output: @ARGV[1].txt!\n";
$query_runner->execute($query);
print OUT $query_runner->printResults();
```

But that does not seem to work, the subroutine printResults() still prints to my terminal instead of the output file. Is there a way to print its output to my outputfile without changing the subroutine of the package itself?

Comment: In addition to the answers, it's worth commenting that a module which doesn't offer an API to fetch the results as a string, rather than print them to the screen, is rather flawed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`select`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/select.html) to set the default print filehandle, eg.

```
select (OUT);
```

Comment: Thanks, but that only works for my own print statements, not the one from $query_runner->printResults();. That one still prints only to my terminal...

Comment: Ok, I can't verify this, but apparently `printResults` takes an optional filehandle argument. try `$query_runner->printResults(\*OUT);`

Comment: `select` usually does not work for modules that call into external C libraries :-(

Answer (score 1):

You can reopen STDOUT to write to the given file, call the printing sub and then restore the old STDOUT:

```
open my $oldout, ">&STDOUT" or die "Can't dup STDOUT: $!";
open STDOUT, '>', $ARGV[1] or die "Can't open $ARGV[1]";
$query_runner->printResults();
open STDOUT, ">&", $oldout or die "Can't dup \$oldout: $!";
```

Answer (score 1):

From https://github.com/pubmed2ensembl/biomart-plus-extras/blob/master/lib/BioMart/QueryRunner.pm :

```
sub printResults {        
        my ($self, $filehandle, $lines) = @_;
        $filehandle ||= \*STDOUT; # in case no fhandle is provided
        ...
}
```

Thus, printResults takes an optional argument of a filehandle to output to. If not provided, it defaults to STDOUT. You would use it as:

```
open(my $output, ">", $ARGV[1]);
$query_runner->execute($query);
$query_runner->printResults($output);
```